# Disable just the past date of the calendar and not the time of tempusdominus

Tags: javascript, jquery, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

How do I just disable the past date of only the calendar and not the time picker in [tempusdominus](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/)?

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker13').datetimepicker({
        inline: true,
        sideBySide: true,
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm',
        minDate: new Date()

    });
});
```

This code just disable both the past date and past time.

Comment: Perhaps  `minDate: new Date(); minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate()-1); minDate.setHours(23,59,59,999)` since the dates seems to be on [day granularity](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Options/#endisableddates)

Comment: Not working. I tried to enabledHours: and list all the hours but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. What worked for me is

```
    $(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker13').datetimepicker({
        showClose: true,
        inline: true,
        sideBySide: true,
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm',
        minDate: new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0),
    });
});
```

Thank you